# Find constants when Vectors are parallel

Tags: vectors

I apologize for the "title".

**Q**: The points A, B and C have position vectors OA = *a*, OB = *b* and OC = *m(2a+b)*. Find **m** if BC is parallel to OA.

**ANS**: 1

I've tried the following:

```
BC = OC - OB
BC = m(2a+b) - b
And;
m(2a+b) - b = k(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$BC=m(2a+b)-b=$$
$$=2ma+(m-1)b$$

What happens if $m=1$.

Comment: hmm, k=2, right?

Comment: @BenAvelson Yeah. $k=2m=2$.

Comment: ooooohhh ***t I feel dumb, o mah god!

Comment: @BenAvelson From now on  you won't.

Comment: oh, thanks, thanks for your time and yes you are right . have a good one!